# Get the set of all unique values in array field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("585901b7875bab86885cf54f"), "foo" : 24, "bar" : [ 1, 2, 5, 6 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("585901be875bab86885cf550"), "foo" : 42, "bar" : [ 3, 4 ] }
```

I want to get all the unique values in the `bar` field, something like:

```
{"_id": "something", "bar": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
```

This is what I tried:

```
db.stuff.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: null, 
    bar: {
      $addToSet: {$each: "$bar"}
    }
  }
}])
```

But complains that `$each` is not a recognized operator.

This does work:

```
db.stuff.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: null, 
    bar: {
      $addToSet: "$bar"
    }
  }
}])
```

But obviously produces a wrong result:

```
{ "_id" : null, "bar" : [ [ 3, 4 ], [ 1, 2, 5, 6 ] ] }
```

---

**EDIT**

I managed to have the result I want by adding a first `$unwind` stage:

```
db.stuff.aggregate([{
  $unwind: { "$bar" },
  $group: {
    _id: null, 
    bar: {
      $addToSet: "$bar"
    }
  }
}])

=> { "_id" : null, "bar" : [ 4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 1 ] }
```

Is it possible at all to make it in one single pipeline stage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) works with array field as well so will beautifully do this.

```
db.stuff.distinct('bar')
```

The aggregation framework is overkill for this and will not perform well

Comment: If Mongo's 16MB size cap is exceeded, the agg framework necessary. `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: distinct too big, 16mb cap, full error`