# How to efficiently get a list of related keys in mongodb records

Tags: mongodb

If I have the records:

```
{ clientId: 1, tags: [ "one", "two" ] }
{ clientId: 1, tags: [ "two", "three" ] }
{ clientId: 2, tags: [ "one", "two", "four" ] }
```

and I want to retrieve a list of the the tags that client #1 has, ex. [ "one", "two", "three" ], how would I do that?

Comment: I agree, depends on which kind of framework do you use, if you want to use a basic find or aggregation and how many records do you have too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the set of all unique values in array field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41240078/get-the-set-of-all-unique-values-in-array-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/), like so:

```
const tags = db.collection.distinct('tags', {clientId: 1});
```

Comment: Any advice on the best index for this?

Comment: yep, just an index on `clientId` would suffice.